# How to Run JavaScript file with node.js on windows (scribbletune)

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible to run a JavaScript file with node.js on windows? I have been trying to for hours and can't find any more solutions on the internet that work.

I have a js-file that uses scribbletune which only works with node.js.
I have node.js installed and I installed gitbash because it was recommended in a forum.
I tried to run from command prompt and gitbash but nothing seems to happen.
What am I doing wrong? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to install gitbash to use Node on Windows. It's a handy thing to have if you're used to a *nix environment. If you're not, it just gives you something more to learn, which isn't helpful if you're already in the middle of trying to learn Node.

Just:

1. Get the Windows installer from https://nodejs.org/en/download/
2. Run the Windows installer
3. Create a directory for your project
4. Open a Command Prompt Window to get a command line
5. Switch to your project directory
6. (Optional, but a good idea) Use `npm init` to create a `package.json` file (it'll walk you through it)
7. Install any libs you're going to be using via `npm` (for instance, `npm install scribbletune` from your command prompt window)
8. Put your JavaScript files in that directory
9. Use `node main.js` at the command line to run your main file (whatever it's called; `main.js` is just a placeholder)

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to run a js (java script file) file

**step 1**. u need to go to the file location where u want to run.

**step 2.** just use "shift +right click".
u will see a pop-up and go to powershell or cmd.

**step 3.** type "node FILENAME.js"

**final step:** you will see the result  ^.^