# How can I print Cypress base Url in the `Git bash CLI console`

Tags: node.js, cypress, git-bash

How can I print Cypress base Url in the `Git bash CLI console` while running the Cypress test ? Could someone please advise ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running headless, the browser logs don't show in the terminal, but those from the Cypress node process (aka `cy.task()`) do show up.

I assume the baseUrl is changing during the test, here is an example that does that and logs the current value using a task.

The configured value is `http://localhost:3000`, the test changes it to `http://localhost:3001`.

**cypress.config.js**

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {

      console.log('Printing baseUrl - during setup', config.baseUrl)

      on('task', {
        logBaseUrl(baseUrl) {
          console.log('Printing baseUrl - from task', baseUrl)
          return null
        }
      })
    },
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000'
  },
})
```

**test**

```js
it('logs baseUrl to the terminal in run mode', () => {

  console.log('Printing baseUrl - directly from test', Cypress.config('baseUrl'))  // no show

  Cypress.config('baseUrl', 'http://localhost:3001')                     
  
  cy.task('logBaseUrl', Cypress.config('baseUrl'))
})
```

**terminal**

```js
Printing baseUrl - during setup http://localhost:3000

====================================================================================================
  Running:  log-baseurl.cy.js                                                               (1 of 1)

Printing baseUrl - from task http://localhost:3001
  √ logs baseUrl to the terminal in run mode (73ms)

  1 passing (115ms)

  (Results)
  ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
  │ Tests:        1                                                                                │
  │ Passing:      1                                                                                │
  │ Failing:      0                                                                                │
  │ Pending:      0                                                                                │
  │ Skipped:      0                                                                                │
  │ Screenshots:  0                                                                                │
  │ Video:        true                                                                             │
  │ Duration:     0 seconds                                                                        │
  │ Spec Ran:     log-baseurl.cy.js                                                                │
  └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
====================================================================================================

  (Run Finished)

       Spec                                              Tests  Passing  Failing  Pending  Skipped
  ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
  │ √  log-baseurl.cy.js                        108ms        1        1        -        -        - │
  └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
    √  All specs passed!                        108ms        1        1        -        -        -

Done in 18.49s.
```

Comment: That seems more precise than my answer. Upvoted.

Comment: @TesterDick Thank you, will be more helpful for people who got two environments like prod, staging to test. So the log will be helpful in which environment the test is pointing while running in headless mode in local or jenkins or docker etc

Comment: Upvoted and accepted the answer.

Comment: @TesterDick Are you familiar with this .env.local file settings in latest cypress version ?>> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74440801/unable-to-read-values-from-env-local-file-in-latest-cypress-version

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [nodejs command `console.log(Cypress.config().baseUrl)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67391413/6309).

That does [not require Git Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45877813/6309) though, only nodejs installed on Your Windows.

Or you can add in your tests `cy.config().baseUrl`.

Comment: Sorry I am running my test in headless mode and looking to print something in cli log and not in browser console !