# Cypress 12: How to set variables locally and in CI -BitBucket so that there are no security concerns

Tags: cypress, bitbucket

In E2E I am using some variables for dashboard, Mailosaur and BrowserStack.

This is the relevent part of `cypress.config.js`

```js
{
  projectId: "XXXX", //dashboard project-id
  "env": {
      MAILOSAUR_API_KEY: "XXXXXX", // Mailosaur email api
      SERVERID: 'XXXX',
      TESTEMAIL: 'XXX'
    },
}
```

Similarly, for `Browserstack.json` these are the variables

```js
{
    "auth": {
        "username": "XXXXX",
        "access_key": "XXXXX"
    },
}
```

How can I define these variables so that I can run my scripts locally and in BitBucket without creating any security issues.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cypress: Passing the param into npm script when run by CL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76162041/cypress-passing-the-param-into-npm-script-when-run-by-cl)

Comment: You can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76162041/cypress-passing-the-param-into-npm-script-when-run-by-cl

Answer (score 2):

For the Cypress sensitive data this question [Unable to read values from .env.local file in latest Cypress version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74440801/unable-to-read-values-from-env-local-file-in-latest-cypress-version) shows a reasonable way to handle sensitive data.

Browserstack keys can be defined on the Account panel, see [BrowserStack access key](https://www.browserstack.com/docs/iaam/security/manage-access-keys)

For Cypress in CI you need to set something like `CYPRESS_MAILOSAUR_API_KEY`, but the problem is there's no way to define the key independently of the checked-in code.

- if you use **command-line settings**, they are hard-coded in `package.json`
- if you use `.env` to hold secrets, it needs to be checked in so that the machine can use it

This blog [Keep passwords secret in E2E tests](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/keep-passwords-secret-in-e2e-tests/) gives a better picture.

> We can set the required environment variable on CircleCI, but I really like the new CircleCI security contexts because they:
>
> - allow explicitly listing the context that a job expects in the circle.yml file
> - inject or stop the job depending on the security permission of the context

See [Using Contexts](https://circleci.com/docs/contexts/), in CircleCI the secrets are set in the dashboard and don't need to be checked in anywhere.

To do the same with Browserstack, you could add a plugin for CircleCI, see [Integrate BrowserStack Automate with CircleCI](https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/selenium/circleci)